# Node: Read data, transform it and write into file using streams and pipe

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

I try to read a string from a text file, encode it and save into a file. I wanna use `pipe` in order to transfer `hash` from `ReadStream` to `WriteStream`. But I don't know how to transform the changed data. My code:

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const fs = require('fs');
let hash = crypto.createHash('md5');
var rs = fs.createReadStream('./passwords.txt');
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./new_passwords.txt');


rs.on('data', function(d) {
  hash.update(d);
});
rs.on('end', function(d) {
    console.log(hash.digest('hex'))
});
```

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use functions such as password_hash, PBKDF2, Bcrypt and similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend a lot of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: i second @zaph on this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_hash) it should be as easy as:

```
const fs = require('fs')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const hash = crypto.createHash('md5')
const rs = fs.createReadStream('./plain.txt')
const ws = fs.createWriteStream('./hashed.txt')

rs.pipe(hash).pipe(ws)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream('./passwords.txt');
var ws = fs.createWriteStream('./new_passwords.txt');
var Transform = require('stream').Transform;
var transformer = new Transform();

transformer._transform = function(data, encoding, cb) {
 // do transformation
 cb();
}

    rs
    .pipe(transformer)
    .pipe(ws);
```